# Get current coords with react native mapbox using function components

Tags: javascript, react-native, maps, mapbox-gl-js

I am using react native with mapbox library and i am doing the following to get the current location on map for the user:

```
   <MapboxGL.MapView          
          surfaceView={true}
          zoomLevel={15}
          logoEnabled={false}
          style={styles.matchParent}>

           <MapboxGL.UserLocation
                visible={true}
                onUpdate={() => onUserLocationUpdate()}
            />

            <MapboxGL.Camera
                followZoomLevel={17} //followUserLocation
                followUserMode={'normal'}
                followUserLocation={true}
                followZoomLevel={17}
                animationDuration={1000}
            />


     </MapboxGL.MapView>
```

based on the [docs](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/UserLocation.md#mapboxgluserlocation-)  is that the prop `onUpdate` is triggered on location update with current coords, so once triggered i am calling  `onUserLocationUpdate()` which do the following:

```
const onUserLocationUpdate = async (location) => {
        //console.log(location)
        let lat = location.coords.latitude;
        let long = location.coords.longitude;
        let alt = location.coords.altitude;
        setlatitude(lat)
        setlongitude(long)
        setaltitude(alt)
}
```

However, I am getting this error:

> ERROR    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'location.coords')

I am using react native function components, however, I have followed this example [here](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/example/src/examples/UserLocationChange.js)  which is using class components and it worked for me but when I convert to function components I got the error

Answer (score 1):

That's a JS thing, not related with Mapbox. Try passing the `location` argument to your function like:

```
onUpdate={(location) => onUserLocationUpdate(location)}
```

Or even better:

```
onUpdate={onUserLocationUpdate}
```